# React: change the state of three buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created only one button component; on the same page I include this component 3 times; two of these will be the same while the third will be different.

I would like to create three buttons, button 1 and button 2 are called "connect" when clicked they must change state and be called "disconnect".
the problem is that with a further click, the status must return to "connect". button 3 must not react to the change of button 1 and 2.

How do I return the state of button 1 and button 2 to their original state?

thank you

file app.js

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


import React, { useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import {Button} from './Button.js'

function App(){
 
  const [label, setLabel] = useState('Connect wallet');
  // const [labelPurchase, setlabelPurchase] = useState('PURCHASE')
const labelPurchase = "PURCHASE";
  var etichetta;
  console.log("1: ", etichetta);
  console.log("label1: ", label);

  if (label == true) {
  
  etichetta = "Connect Wallet"
  console.log("2: ", etichetta);
  console.log("label2: ", label);
  label = false

} else {

etichetta = "Connect"
console.log("3: ", etichetta);
console.log("label3: ", label);

}


return(
  
  <>

    <Button label={label} setLabel={setLabel}/>
      
    <Button label={label} setLabel={setLabel}/>

    <Button label={labelPurchase}/>

  </>

  
  
  
)

}


export default App;
```

file button.js

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from "react";
import './Button.css';

export const Button=({label,setLabel}) =>{

  function connect() {
    setLabel('nuovo')
  }

  return (

  <button onClick={connect}> {label} </button>

  )
}
```

Comment: If button 1 is clicked to "connect" does that mean button 2 also clicks to "connect" automatically, but button 3 doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that "links" the first two buttons together - when one is updated the other updates along with it. The third button is not linked and is therefore unaffected by the other two buttons.

The code doesn't explicitly define each button in the JSX but uses a button config array that defines each button; the config is passed into the main component.

```js
const { useState } = React;

// Pass in the button config
function Example({ config }) {

  // Initialise the state with it
  const [ buttons, setButtons ] = useState(config);

  // When a button is clicked...
  function handleClick(e) {
    
    // Destructure its name, and its type from its
    // dataset
    const { name, dataset: { type } } = e.target;
        
    // If it's a linked button, map over the buttons in state
    // and update the `connect` property 
    if (type === 'linked') {

      const updated = buttons.map(button => {
        if (button.linked) button.connect = !button.connect;
        return button;
      });

      // Set the new state
      setButtons(updated);

    }
    
    // If the button has a "single" type
    // locate its index in the array, and update its
    // `connect` property
    if (type === 'single') {

      const copy = [...buttons];

      const index = copy.findIndex(button => {
        return button.name === name;
      });

      copy[index].connect = !copy[index].connect;

      // Update the state
      setButtons(copy);

    }
    
  }

  // Iterate over the buttons state to create
  // the buttons
  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map(button => {
        const { name, linked, connect } = button;
        return (
          <Button
            name={name}
            type={linked ? 'linked' : 'single'}
            state={connect}
            handleClick={handleClick}
          />        
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );

}

// Build a button
function Button(props) {
  
  const {
    name,
    type,
    state,
    handleClick
  } = props;
    
  const buttonStyle = [
    'button',
    state && 'disconnect',
    !state && 'connect'
  ].join(' ');
  
  return (
    <button
      className={buttonStyle}
      type="button"
      data-type={type}
      name={name}
      onClick={handleClick}
    >{state ? 'Disconnect' : 'Connect'}
    </button>
  );
}

const config = [
  { name: 'button1', linked: true, connect: false },
  { name: 'button2', linked: true, connect: false },
  { name: 'button3', linked: false, connect: false },
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example config={config} />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
button { font-size: 1em; width: 100px; }
button:not(:last-child) { margin-right: 0.25em; }
button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.connect { color: green; }
.disconnect { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```